Pandas ffill conditional upon another column
I have the following snippet from a larger dataframe:
pd.DataFrame({
    'sig_2':[False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False,
             False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False,
             False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True],
    'tr_cnt':[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2],
    'fls_cnt':[53, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'test1':[0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 16, 16],
    'test2':[54, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'check1':[False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
              False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
              False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False]})

tr_cnt is simply the count of successive True rows in sig_2 while fls_cnt does the same for the False rows. test1 and test2 are the total counts of the successive rows. check1 is where the following condition is True:
df['test1'] > 2) & (df['fls_cnt'].shift(1) >= 2)
What i would like to do is forward fill the True values in the check1 column by the corresponding value in the test1 column.
For example, the first True row in the check1 column has a corresponding value of 9 in the test column. Thus, i would like to forward fill this value by another 8 rows. The next True has a correpsonding value of 4 so i want this to forward fill by another 3 rows.
I have tried the following different methods:
mask = (df['test1'] > 2) & (df['fls_cnt'].shift(1) >= 2)

# Trial 1
groups = mask.ne(mask.shift()).cumsum()
df['test1'] = df.groupby(groups)['test1'].ffill().astype(bool)


# Trial 2
df['test2'] = df.groupby(mask)['test1'].ffill().astype(bool)


# Trial 3
groups = (~mask).cumsum()
df['test3'] = df.groupby(groups)['test1'].ffill().astype(bool)

# Trial 4
df["test4"] = df.groupby(mask.cumsum())['test1'].ffill().fillna(False).astype(bool)

In all of these methods, they seem to do what i want where the condition is True, but they are also including rows that dont satisfy this condition which is odd.

It's unclear what is the input and the expected output, can you clarify?

As @mozway points out in the comments to your question, it is a little unclear what you are trying to do. I suggest here my interpretation of your logic. If it isn't what you were expecting, I'll simply remove the answer. But in that case, I also suggest you review you question and elaborate, be more clear:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sig_2': [False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False,
              False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False,
              False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True],
    'tr_cnt': [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2],
    'fls_cnt': [53, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'test1': [0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 16, 16],
    'test2': [54, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'check1': [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
               False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
               False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False]
})
df['forward_fill'] = False  

for i in df.index[df['check1']]:
    end_index = i + df.at[i, 'test1']  
    if end_index > len(df):
        end_index = len(df)
    
    df.loc[i:end_index, 'forward_fill'] = True

print(df)


Which gives:
   sig_2  tr_cnt  fls_cnt  test1  test2  check1  forward_fill
0   False       0       53      0     54   False         False
1   False       0       54      0     54   False         False
2    True       1        0      9      0    True          True
3    True       2        0      9      0   False          True
4    True       3        0      9      0   False          True
5    True       4        0      9      0   False          True
6    True       5        0      9      0   False          True
7    True       6        0      9      0   False          True
8    True       7        0      9      0   False          True
9    True       8        0      9      0   False          True
10   True       9        0      9      0   False          True
11  False       0        1      0      4   False          True
12  False       0        2      0      4   False         False
13  False       0        3      0      4   False         False
14  False       0        4      0      4   False         False
15   True       1        0      1      0   False         False
16  False       0        1      0      1   False         False
17   True       1        0      9      0   False         False
18   True       2        0      9      0   False         False
19   True       3        0      9      0   False         False
20   True       4        0      9      0   False         False
21   True       5        0      9      0   False         False
22   True       6        0      9      0   False         False
23   True       7        0      9      0   False         False
24   True       8        0      9      0   False         False
25   True       9        0      9      0   False         False
26  False       0        1      0      4   False         False
27  False       0        2      0      4   False         False
28  False       0        3      0      4   False         False
29  False       0        4      0      4   False         False
30   True       1        0      4      0    True          True
31   True       2        0      4      0   False          True
32   True       3        0      4      0   False          True
33   True       4        0      4      0   False          True
34  False       0        1      0      1   False          True
35   True       1        0     16      0   False         False
36   True       2        0     16      0   False         False

Update: An alternative way (more vectorized) would be:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sig_2': [False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False,
              False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False,
              False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True],
    'tr_cnt': [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2],
    'fls_cnt': [53, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'test1': [0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 16, 16],
    'test2': [54, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'check1': [False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
               False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
               False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False]
})

indices = np.repeat(df.index[df['check1']], df['test1'][df['check1']])
ranges = np.concatenate([np.arange(start, start + length) for start, length in zip(df.index[df['check1']], df['test1'][df['check1']])])
mask = np.zeros(len(df), dtype=bool)
mask[ranges] = True
df['forward_fill'] = mask
print(df)

which retunrs the same output:
    sig_2  tr_cnt  fls_cnt  test1  test2  check1  forward_fill
0   False       0       53      0     54   False         False
1   False       0       54      0     54   False         False
2    True       1        0      9      0    True          True
3    True       2        0      9      0   False          True
4    True       3        0      9      0   False          True
5    True       4        0      9      0   False          True
6    True       5        0      9      0   False          True
7    True       6        0      9      0   False          True
8    True       7        0      9      0   False          True
9    True       8        0      9      0   False          True
10   True       9        0      9      0   False          True
11  False       0        1      0      4   False         False
12  False       0        2      0      4   False         False
13  False       0        3      0      4   False         False
14  False       0        4      0      4   False         False
15   True       1        0      1      0   False         False
16  False       0        1      0      1   False         False
17   True       1        0      9      0   False         False
18   True       2        0      9      0   False         False
19   True       3        0      9      0   False         False
20   True       4        0      9      0   False         False
21   True       5        0      9      0   False         False
22   True       6        0      9      0   False         False
23   True       7        0      9      0   False         False
24   True       8        0      9      0   False         False
25   True       9        0      9      0   False         False
26  False       0        1      0      4   False         False
27  False       0        2      0      4   False         False
28  False       0        3      0      4   False         False
29  False       0        4      0      4   False         False
30   True       1        0      4      0    True          True
31   True       2        0      4      0   False          True
32   True       3        0      4      0   False          True
33   True       4        0      4      0   False          True
34  False       0        1      0      1   False         False
35   True       1        0     16      0   False         False
36   True       2        0     16      0   False         False


thanks for the quick response. what you have done is pretty much what i wanted, the only expection was i changed end_index to end_index = i + df.at[i, 'test1'] - 1. Is it possible to do this using a vectorization approach?

@MichaelFelman I update my answer to also respond to your comment.

IIUC, what you want is a simple transform('any') on the successive True if you have True in check1:
group = df['sig_2'].ne(df['sig_2'].shift()).cumsum()
df['out'] = df['check1'].groupby(group).transform('any')

Output:
    sig_2  tr_cnt  fls_cnt  test1  test2  check1    out
0   False       0       53      0     54   False  False
1   False       0       54      0     54   False  False
2    True       1        0      9      0    True   True
3    True       2        0      9      0   False   True
4    True       3        0      9      0   False   True
5    True       4        0      9      0   False   True
6    True       5        0      9      0   False   True
7    True       6        0      9      0   False   True
8    True       7        0      9      0   False   True
9    True       8        0      9      0   False   True
10   True       9        0      9      0   False   True
11  False       0        1      0      4   False  False
12  False       0        2      0      4   False  False
13  False       0        3      0      4   False  False
14  False       0        4      0      4   False  False
15   True       1        0      1      0   False  False
16  False       0        1      0      1   False  False
17   True       1        0      9      0   False  False
18   True       2        0      9      0   False  False
19   True       3        0      9      0   False  False
20   True       4        0      9      0   False  False
21   True       5        0      9      0   False  False
22   True       6        0      9      0   False  False
23   True       7        0      9      0   False  False
24   True       8        0      9      0   False  False
25   True       9        0      9      0   False  False
26  False       0        1      0      4   False  False
27  False       0        2      0      4   False  False
28  False       0        3      0      4   False  False
29  False       0        4      0      4   False  False
30   True       1        0      4      0    True   True
31   True       2        0      4      0   False   True
32   True       3        0      4      0   False   True
33   True       4        0      4      0   False   True
34  False       0        1      0      1   False  False
35   True       1        0     16      0   False  False
36   True       2        0     16      0   False  False

